# He has become a criminal and he has been a criminal

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning, present-perfect

Suppose my friend John was a good person. He used to help others. But recently he has changed. He has become a criminal. Therefore I can say,

**John has become a criminal.**

We often use *be* in the place of *become*. Can I rewrite this sentence as,

**John has been a criminal.**
(Though this sentence means that he became criminal at some point in the past and since then he is still criminal)

Comment: Nope, they do not imply the same meaning.

Comment: No. _Become_ means to change state; a normal predicate noun  with auxiliary _be_ implies a state but not a change of state.

Comment: "We often use be in the place of become." Can you cite a source for that or provide some examples? (The sense of "become" might be implied, as in "tomorrow I will be a graduate of the university", but "be" and "become" aren't really the same, so I'm not sure about what you mean.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan "I want to become a doctor" is rewritten as "I want to be a doctor".

Comment: Those are not really the same. The implication in the second is that I am not currently a doctor, but that is not the literal meaning.

Comment: Does the sentence "I want to become a doctor" not mean I'm not currently a doctor?

Comment: Yes, "become" means to change from one state to another. "Be" does not literally mean that, although that meaning might be implied.

Comment: For this particular example I can't find any difference in meaning of them.

Comment: Let's say that a medical board is considering whether to revoke a doctor's license. It asks why he wants to remain in the profession, so he says, "I want to be a doctor!" He wouldn't say "I want to become a doctor!" since he already is one. The meanings are different.

Comment: In case it's relevant to what you're trying to convey, I think that saying someone is (or has become) a criminal would imply to a native speaker that he has committed an *actual* crime.  If you mean to describe someone who's just being sneaky, telling lies, or just being a generally bad person, then you might want to phrase this differently.

Answer (score 9):

> 1: *John has become a criminal.*

Unambiguously asserts that John became a criminal inb the past (by very strong implication, *recently*), AND that *he's **still** a criminal*.

> 2: *John has been a criminal.*

As a standalone utterance, asserts that *at some point in the past* (not necessarily *recently*) John became a criminal, BUT it very strongly implies that *he's **no longer** a criminal*.

Note - that strong implication *can* be overridden. For example,...

> 3: *John has been a criminal **ever since he was a teenager**.*

Comment: "We've been friends" implies we're no longer friends and "We've been friends for 10 years" implies we're still friends. Right?

Comment: Yes, and as an example for your #2: "John has been a criminal, a vagabond, and a snake-oil salesman, but he is now a well-respected congressman." (Let's assume that "congressman" is mutually exclusive with those other three occupations...)

Comment: @SahilLaskar: No. "We've been friends" just implies the speaker isn't a native Anglophone! We'd only use that sequence of words if it continued... *We've been friends **since childhood***, as per my example #3

Comment: Also note that in "real" (spoken) language, (uncontracted) *We have been friends but we're enemies now* would almost *always* be delivered with heavy stress on either or both of ***have*** and ***been*** (or *feasibly* heavy stress on both ***friends*** and ***enemies***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm interested in the implication part of this sentence. `John has been a criminal.` AND `John had been a criminal.` I was under the notion that **John had been** would strongly imply that John is no longer a criminal. However, **John has been** could go either way.

Would this be a fair assessment? Your thought, Please.

Comment: You're completely mistaken. The *only* reason for using Past Perfect is if you're in some kind of "narrative" context where the *temporal focus* of the narrative ***is already in the past***  (and you're referring to something ***earlier than that***). In a *current conversation* talking about John *today*, you might use Present Perfect to underline that he *was*, but *is no longer* a criminal - but learners would usually do better sticking to Simple Past *John **was** a criminal [but he's an honest man now]*.

Comment: e.g. *When I first met John **last year**, I knew that he **had been** a criminal. But he assured me that was all in the past, and that he was now "going straight"*. Note that ***now*** in that example refers to ***the time in the past when I first met John***, not the time when I was saying / writing that text.